# Reading XML and extract only value

Tags: xml

What is the easiest way to extract just the value set in a XML file? For example the data in the XML file is

```
<node name="host">
  <map>
    <entry key="cipher_strength" value="low" />
    <entry key="port" value="78234" />
    <entry key="over_ssl" value="false" />
    <entry key="using_fips" value="true" />
    <entry key="ssl_keystore" value="lib/ssl" />
  </map>
</node>
```

I just want to display `low` from the script.

Here is the `sed` command i am using that does return the full string

```
sed -n '/cipher_strength/{s/.*<cipher_strength>//;s/<\/cipher_strength.*Value=""//;p;}' test.xml
```

Following on from a comment, I can't use `xmlstarlet` as this is not available on my version of suse and is locked down by the vendor so unable to install.

Comment: The easiest way is with `xmlstarlet` or one of the other XML-aware tools. Provide the first line of your file (the xmlns part) and a skeleton of the file and someone will give you a full answer.

Comment: I can't use xmlstarlet as this is not available on my version of suse and is locked down so unable to install.  I can read the XML string very easy using sed -n but it reads the full sting and only need to return the value from the string.  Here is the sed command i am using that does return the full string.  sed -n '/cipher_strength/{s/.*<cipher_strength>//;s/<\/cipher_strength.*Value=""//;p;}' test.xml

Comment: Ask your administrators to install it. Arguably this would be business need.

Comment: I am the administrator and we are not able to install because this is vendor appliance with locked down linux kernel with limited command toolset.  I have been looking at xmlinit as as an option but unable to get the exact value we are needing to fetch.  This is the XML file structure and only need to fetch the value attribute.  <node name="host">
 <map>
  <key="cipher_strength" value="low" />
 </map>

Comment: Or in fact, many of the results of [tag:xmllint]

Answer (score 2):

Using the command line XML parser `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//entry[@key="cipher_strength"]/@value' -nl file.xml
```

This will match all `entry` nodes anywhere in the XML document, and will extract the value of their `value` attributes if the same `entry` node has a `key` attribute whose value is `cipher_strength`.  Each value will be outputted with a trailing newline character.

The `xmllint` implementations that are available on various systems seems to vary in their support for doing XPath queries.

On my OpenBSD system, you can do

```
xmllint --xpath '//entry[@key="cipher_strength"]/@value' file.xml
```

to get back

```
 value="low"
```

However, `xmllint --xpath '//entry[@key="cipher_strength"]/@value/text()' file.xml`, which I would have assumed would give me the string `low`, does not seem to work (just generates a `XPath set is empty` response).

As long as the values for the `value` attribute are "nice", you should be able to massage this output to extract the actual value:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//entry[@key="cipher_strength"]/@value' file.xml | sed -e 's/^[^"]*"//' -e 's/"$//'
low
```

The `sed` expressions above removes everything up to the first double quote character, and then also cuts off the last double quote character, from each line.

Other `xmllint` implementations/versions may have go the path of using `xmllint --shell`:

```
xmllint --shell file.xml <<<'cat //entry[@key="cipher_strength"]/@value' |
sed -e '/^[^ ]/d' -e 's/^[^"]*"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

Comment: Using the //entry/@value will not work because the XML file structure is constructed like this. <node name="host">
 <map>
  <key="cipher_strength" value="low" />
  <key="port" value="78234" />
  <key="over_ssl" value="false" />
  <key="using_fips" value="true" />
  <key="ssl_keystore" value="lib/ssl" /> 
 </map>

Comment: @BrianH An XPath query that starts with `//` searches recursively through the document until it matches something. It does not match the explicit path from the root node.  Also, did you leave the `entry` node name out from the XML in your comment by mistake?

Comment: I understand the // will search the whole xml file but i need to search for a specific key and display the value that is currently set in the xml file.   In my example I am searching for cipher_strength and need to display the output of low.

Comment: @BrianH Sorry, I missed that part as you did not mention it in the question other than in the code (and since you only posted a very short example document, I wasn't aware that it was important). My answer is updated.

Comment: looks like my implementation of xmllint will not work and trying to see if i can get grep with awk to work now.

Answer (score 0):

If no dedicated XML tools are available, you might want to try it with `awk`: The call

```
user@host~$ awk '/key="cipher_strength"/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (split($i,parts,"=")==2 && parts[1]=="value") print parts[2]}}' file.xml
```

would look for all lines which contain `key="cipher_strength"` and then split all the space-delimited strings at the `=` sign. For all those that contain that sign "in the middle" (i.e. there is one part before and one after it), check if the first part equals `value`, and print the second if it does. For your input, I get

```
user@host~$ awk '/key="cipher_strength"/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (split($i,parts,"=")==2 && parts[1]=="value") print parts[2]}}' file.xml
"low"
```

If there are more `<node>` nodes, you could try to modify the program in order to ensure you are in the right one before applying this action.